# Standby router is not found although HSRP is working properly. Why?

Tags: packet-tracer, hsrp

I implemented HSRP in a project in packet tracer. Although HSRP is working properly show standby brief gives the following output. What is strange, that If the first router is enabled DHCP stops working for the VLAN 241. On the other hand If I disable the first router and the standby router takes over DHCP works fine for all VLAN's.

(This output is produced after re-enabling R1)

I already tried for several hours to fix this issue without success.

[image: R1 show standby brief]

R2 gives output:

[image: R2 show standby brief]

R1 script:

```
 Current configuration : 3023 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
enable password class
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
username Administrator password 0 Pasw0rd+
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524HE77-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.25
 encapsulation dot1Q 25
 ip address 1.0.0.4 255.255.255.248
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::5 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC04::1/64
 standby 25 ip 1.0.0.1
 standby 25 priority 105
 standby 25 preempt
 standby 25 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.240
 encapsulation dot1Q 240
 ip address 10.15.240.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MITARBEITER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MITARBEITER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC00::1/64
 standby 240 ip 10.15.240.1
 standby 240 priority 105
 standby 240 preempt
 standby 240 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.241
 encapsulation dot1Q 241
 ip address 10.15.241.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MGMT in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MGMT_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC01::1/64
 standby 241 ip 10.15.241.1
 standby 241 priority 105
 standby 241 preempt
 standby 241 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.242
 encapsulation dot1Q 242
 ip address 10.15.242.9 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group SERVER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter SERVER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC02::1/64
 standby 242 ip 10.15.242.1
 standby 242 priority 105
 standby 242 preempt
 standby 242 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.243
 encapsulation dot1Q 243
 ip address 10.15.243.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group GAESTE in
 ipv6 traffic-filter GAESTE_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC03::1/64
 standby 243 ip 10.15.243.1
 standby 243 priority 105
 standby 243 preempt
 standby 243 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 209.165.240.2 255.255.255.248
 ip access-group ESTABLISHED in
 ip nat outside
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC05::1/64
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Serial0/0/0 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
ipv6 route ::/0 Serial0/0/0
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 permit ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 1.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

R2 script:

```
 Current configuration : 2611 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
enable password class
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524X749-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.25
 encapsulation dot1Q 25
 ip address 1.0.0.5 255.255.255.248
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::A link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC04::2/64
 standby 25 ip 1.0.0.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.240
 encapsulation dot1Q 240
 ip address 10.15.240.10 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MITARBEITER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MITARBEITER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::6 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC00::2/64
 standby 240 ip 10.15.240.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.241
 encapsulation dot1Q 241
 ip address 10.15.241.10 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MGMT in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MGMT_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::7 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC01::2/64
 standby 241 ip 10.15.241.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.242
 encapsulation dot1Q 242
 ip address 10.15.242.10 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group SERVER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter SERVER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::8 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC02::2/64
 standby 242 ip 10.15.242.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.243
 encapsulation dot1Q 243
 ip address 10.15.243.10 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group GAESTE in
 ipv6 traffic-filter GAESTE_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::9 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC03::2/64
 standby 243 ip 10.15.243.1
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 209.167.240.10 255.255.255.252
 ipv6 traffic-filter ESTABLISHED_IPv6 in
 ip nat outside
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC06::1/64
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Serial0/0/0 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
ipv6 route ::/0 Serial0/0/0
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 permit ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 1.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
no cdp run
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

[image: project]

Comment: Either we are not getting the full configuration, or you are applying ACLs that do not exist.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have removed the ACL's since they complicated other taks, but I will add them later. Can this cause this issue?

Comment: If you reference non-existent ACLs, you get the implied deny any any.

Comment: But I'm able to ping servers on the outside network and on the inside network. From VLAN 240 on which there is an empty ACL

Comment: We cannot answer for Packet Tracer because it is not real IOS, and it has various bugs and is missing many features because it is only designed to help you pass the CCNA. It is not really something used in a real business network by network professionals as is required for questions here.

Comment: Ok. I removed the application of the ACL's however the problem persists. It's probably a bug then.

Comment: DHCP is not aware of HSRP state and does not appear in any configuration I see so I'm not sure how that would be involved. I see IP Helper configuration though. In any case, do one thing at a time and make sure each feature/function works before adding complexity.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer DHCP is running on a server and it is working fine as long as the link to R1 is deactivated. However when R1 becomes primary it is no longer working.

Comment: That is what I imagined and leads me to assume that there is a basic configuration mistake on that router, IP overlap or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

I set the native vlan to the management vlan for all trunk ports. I copied this from a solution I received from my professor. However for WLAN to work it is only necessary that the ports which are connected to the switch where the WAP and wlan controller operate have the native vlan changed to the management vlan since WLAC or WAP does not support vlan tags. If all trunking ports within the network change their native vlan to the management vlan it seems to introduce problems with DHCP.

EDIT: According to my professor, this is indeed the correct solution he didn't specify why though.

Comment: Excellent - please don't forget to accept your answer (when it becomes possible), so the question doesn't keep popping up forever.

Comment: @Zac67 My professor says I need to set the native VLAN I use for WLAC / WAP for all trunk ports. But then I have the error described above. It is also not necessary in order to have functioning WLAN. Is my professor wrong? (He is somewhat confused from time to time and I'm a newb in this field.